# Using SUM for first n rows in each group in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table with two columns (client_id and spent). Each client bought something more than 20 times. I want to sum spendings for each client.
I know that I can use `sum` and `group by` to do that, but I want to use `sum` not for all values in the groups but for only first 10 values. How can I do that?
I have tried with top 10 and limit 10, but It does not work.

I have 10 different clients and more than 200 rows. Clients are not scattered, they are in order, so I have 20 rows on client1 than 20 rows of on client2... Each client appears more than 20 times. I want to use sum and group by, but I do not want to sum all values (more than 20 for each row) , i want to sum first 10 values. Its ordered by time for each client

```
select client_id, sum(spendings)
from my_table
group by client_id
```

Comment: Try to add row number per id and the keep RN < 11 before applying the group by.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 'first 10 values.' is this by time, value, product? can you more specific?

Comment: I have 10 different clients and more than 200 rows. Clients are not scattered \ they are in order, so I have 20 rows on client1 than 20 rows of on client2...
Each client appears more than 20 times.
I want to use sum and group by, but I do not want to sum all values (more than 20 for each row) , i want to sum first 10 values. Its by time

Comment: What's the column name of the timestamp?

Comment: 'they are in order' - of what ? date, auto_increment id?BTW there is no intrinsic order in the way data is stored in sql. It would be helpful if you added your table definition

Comment: order by time but I do not have time columns. Imagine group that has 20 rows, I want to sum first 10

Comment: In which case 'first' has no meaning in this context

Comment: Without a column to order by, there is no order, as @P.Salmon already pointed out, and therefore no first *n*.

Comment: Nor are you guaranteed to get the same 'first 10' every time you run a query

Comment: The next question is why do you only want to sum the first 10 records? You could introduce all sorts of bias..

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Mysql 8.0, You can do this by using window function.

```
select client_id, sum(spendings)
from (select client_id, spendings, row_number() over (partition by client_id order by <timecol>) rn
      from my_table) t
where rn < 11
group by client_id
```

Comment: this shows me an error in second line (I think that row_number() is the problem)

Comment: Have you replaced <timecol> with your correct column.

Comment: yes, it marks me `(partition by client_id order by <timecol>)` as error, the brackets

Comment: You need to replace the <timecol> with your date column. If your table doesn't have any date column, just replace it with null.

Comment: I have done that, I have tried with my date column and with null, and it always shows me the syntax error in this segment `(partition by client_id order by null)` and it marks me the brackets

Comment: column name must be without brackets.

Comment: Which MySQL version you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197201/discussion-between-taga-and-ankit-bajpai).

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL, try this following code-

```
SELECT client_id,SUM(spendings) 
FROM
(
    select client_id, 
    spendings,
    @row_num :=IF(client_id = @client_id,@row_num+1,1)AS RowNumber,
    @client_id := client_id
    FROM my_table   
    ORDER BY client_id
    -- You may need to add here appropriate ordering 
    -- To get your desired 10 rows for group by in the result
)A 
WHERE A.RowNumber < 11
GROUP BY client_id
```